# javax.faces.el.ReferenceSyntaxException: Missing closing quote

Tags: jsf, weblogic, el

I have a jsf1.1 application that works fine on OCJ4 server.
I have deployed it now  to weblogic12.

But I am getting error on EL

javax.faces.el.ReferenceSyntaxException: Missing closing quote.

Can anybody please help me resolve this problem..?

```
<f:loadBundle basename="com.ApplicationResources" var="msgs"/>
  <% response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); %>
    <f:view>
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
          <link href='../stylesheet/vim_stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
          <title>
            <h:outputText value="#{msgs[\'vim.common.vim\']} #{msgs[\'vim.pageheader.dashboard\']}"/>
          </title>
```

I am getting exception

```
javax.faces.el.ReferenceSyntaxException: Missing closing quote. 
Expression: '#{msgs[\'vim.common.vim\']} #{msgs[\'vim.pageheader.dashboard\']}'
```

Comment: well, you could provide the part of your code which throws Exception to help us help you.

Comment: Put it into update of your post please, this is really unreadable:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get rid of the `\`

```
<h:outputText value="#{msgs['vim.common.vim']} #{msgs['vim.pageheader.dashboard']}"/>
```

Comment: It worked but I am getting this error now  javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Cannot get value for expression '#{backing_b
ean_dashboard.m_dtDashboardDataTable}'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSF 2.0 then you don't have to put your msgs into `<h:outputText >`, this
`#{msgs['vim.common.vim']} #{msgs['vim.pageheader.dashboard']}` is enough (you should also remove the backslashes)

If not, try splitting it into two outputTexts, I am not sure if you can combine expressions like this.

Comment: Then try to split it and remove backslashes as Daniel suggested